# Join fields in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read a similar questions but it didn't work!

I Have a table like this:

```
ID      IDParent       Name
---------------------------
01                     Parent
02      01             Child01
02      01             Child02
```

I Have to write a Query that returns the following table:

```
ID      Name1          Name
---------------------------  
01                     Parent
02      Parent         Child01
02      Parent         Child02
```

I tried this query but it did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable  
JOIN SomeTable  ON SomeTable.ID = SomeTable.IDParent;
```

Comment: What are you trying to query? Where is Name1 coming from? The relationship you are trying to query isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use table alias here:

```
SELECT t.Id, p.Name AS Name1, t.Name
FROM Table t
JOIN Table p ON p.ID = t.IDParent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating the alias of your class known as `self join` like this:-

```
SELECT t.Id, p.Name as name, t.Name
FROM Table t
JOIN Table p ON p.ID = t.IDParent;
```